# Firebase user Model. Can't create a firebase model

Tags: reactjs, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need help using firebase with flutter. I'm new to firebase,I worked with nodejs. I don't know how to design a user model with firebase, I don't know if the user models like sex, isAdmin and so on are collections or documents, I'm confused here.  **Please Help**. Thanks

Comment: Before asking questions on stackoveflow, you should have a base knowledge and have at least made a minimal research on google. Everything you need to know to start is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: Are you asking about Flutter or the Firebase Realtime Database? If it's the RTDB, there really are not model as it's an NoSQL environment. There are only parent and child nodes with a limited amount of primitive data types. Perhaps if you can be more specific, we can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's in flutter.
But in android you simple make an object and you have to do default constructor.

and then you simple use the firebase api to read and write.
[look at the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/set.html)